# composed name of models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working with RoR with a legacy database in spanish language.
I have the table and `registropersona` and model `RegistroPersona`. Now I want to run `rails generate scaffold_controller registro_persona` But the generated name of controller should be 
`RegistrosPersonasController` (Note the final **s** in Registros and Personas).
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either edit your `config/initializers/infletions.rb` file to support that, or just rename the controller manually.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to specify the controller name using `scaffold_controller` without also affecting the model name. I've looked around and haven't been able to find anything that does what you're looking for.

I believe you have two options:

1 - use `rails generate controller RegistrosPersonas`. The downside is you end up with a blank controller, and you'd have to fill in all of the REST methods yourself.

2 - use `rails generate scaffold_controller RegistrosPersonas`. This will create the REST methods for you, however all of the model references will use the pluralized name (ie you'll see `RegistrosPersonas.all`). So the downside is that you'll need to go through the controller and change each reference from `RegistrosPersonas` to `RegistroPersona`. Hopefully you should simply be able to use a simple find + replace in whatever text editor or IDE you're using.

Hope that helps somewhat.