# Undefined local variable or method new_ composed spanish model name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working with RoR with a legacy database in spanish language. I have the table and `registropersona` and model `RegistroPersona` and `RegistrosPersonasController`.

When `RegistrosPersonasController/index` is rendered I get the error

> undefined local variable or method new_registro_persona_path for #<#Class:0xb5d2296c>:0xa5f82a0>

Here is my code:

**registro_persona.rb**

```
class RegistroPersona < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "registrospersonas"
end
```

**registros_personas_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrosPersonasController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_registro_persona, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @registros_personas = RegistroPersona.all
  end
end
```

**inflections.rb**

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'registro_persona', 'registros_personas'
end
```

This is the output from command `rake routes | grep registro_persona`

```
 new_registro_persona GET    /registros_personas/new(.:format)      registros_personas#new
edit_registro_persona GET    /registros_personas/:id/edit(.:format) registros_personas#edit
     registro_persona GET    /registros_personas/:id(.:format)      registros_personas#show
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with routing.

`new_registro_odontologico_path` - this is an unknown route for your app

And do not forget to **RESTART your server** after the routes are changed.

Comment: why routing? The controller works fine if I delete the line that contains `new_registro_odontologico_path`

Comment: post your `routes.rb` (or give the uoutput for `rake routes | grep registro_odontologico`). You have `new_registro_odontologico_path` in the view and Rails can build an url using  this method (or this path is called from controller? - I see it nowhere)

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my post is `persona` instead of `odontologico`

Comment: ok I see. Find the code which calls this route `new_registro_persona_path` - maybe you call it incorrectly

Comment: That code was generated by rails when I ran `rails g scaffold_controller registro_persona`. Also you can see the my [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773021/composed-name-of-models-in-rails/19773865?noredirect=1#19773865)

Comment: unfortunately I can't see result of scaffolding (I can't reproduce it locally). Another idea: have you restart your server after adding routes?

Comment: I have been restart the server and works. I feel stupid. You can add the solution in your answer and I will accept it.